# ¿Cómo poner dos search en una misma pagína web?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, php7, wamp

Mi problema consiste en que tengo una tabla de cuatro columnas que genero con `html` y `php` con base a una consulta que realizo en `mysql`, pero en el encabezado de esta tabla, el cliente me pide que le ponga un search a cada columna, para un solo search si se como se hace, pero al intentar poner mas de uno, todos dejan de funcionar, si me pueden ayudar por favor. dejo mi código para que me ayuden. gracias. estas son dos de las columnas en las que debo poner search

```html
<th scope="col">
    <form method="post" class="form-signin col-12">
        <input type="search" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required>
        <button id="VER_FAC" class="btn btn-sm vervacantes btn-block" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Buscar archivos</button>
    </form>
    <th scope="col">
        <form method="post" class="form-signin col-12">
            <input type="search" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Parte del nombre" required>
            <button id="VER_FAC" class="btn btn-sm vervacantes btn-block" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Buscar archivos</button>
        </form>
    </th>
```

aqui es donde mando llamr la funcion que me realiza la consulta de acuerdo al campo del search, y que es donde tengo problema para que me identifique todos los search´s, ya que sí repito la condición y solo cambio el name del input no funciona.

```
include "db.php";
if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $files = get_imgs_porid();
else
    $files = search_genriconombre($_POST['name']);
```

Y aquí están las funciones que hacen la consulta de acuerdo al search que se ejecuta, por separado todos funcionan bien, pero si pongo los cuatro ya no

```
function search_genriconombre($search){
  $images = array();
  $con = con();
  $query=$con->query('select * from image where src like "%'.$search.'%"');
  while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
    $images[] = $r;
  }
  return $images;
}

function get_imgs_porid(){
  $images = array();
  $con = con();
  $query=$con->query("select * from image order by id desc");
  while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
    $images[] = $r;
  }
  return $images;
}

function search_genricoid($search){
  $images =    array();
  $con = con();
  $query=$con->query('select * from image where id ='.$search.'');
  while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
    $images[] = $r;
  }
  return $images;
}

function get_imgs_porestado(){
  $images = array();
  $con = con();
  $query=$con->query("select * from image order by estado desc");
  while($r=$query->fetch_object()){
     $images[] = $r;
  }
  return $images;
}
```

espero su ayuda, de antemano gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Los search son obligatorios los cuatro o no? ¿Versan sobre la misma columna de la tabla o sobre columnas distintas cada uno?

Comment: son cuatro columnas, una es el id, el nombre, la fecha, y estado, donde el cliente quiere que haya un buscador para cada columna, por ejmplo, si el id=15, aparezca todo el registro del id=15, si busca por nombre por ejemplo: nombre =juan que aparezca todo el registro de juan.

Comment: Tienes que poner un "name" distinto por cada buscador y por cada botón de buscar. Luego en PHP según se haya pulsado el botón buscar por ID o buscar por Nombre (Por ejemplo) realizas una consulta u otra.

Comment: entonces la condicion que ya tengo: if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $files = get_imgs_porid();
else
    $files = search_genriconombre($_POST['name']); la repito solamente le cambio el name, por ejemplo, al formulario le pongo name1, y al segunodo name2, y eso es lo que debo poner en el (_POST['name1']) y (_POST['name2']) y poner la consulta que le corresponde ????